# on IE7 span create "newline"?

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BBH5T/4/) code :

```
<div class="richiedi_info_item">
    <label>Message</label>
    <span style="color:Red;">&nbsp;*</span>                                                                
    <div class="richiedi_info_item_nota">     
        <a id="notaInfo" href="javascript:void(0);">Click</a>            
    </div>
</div>

.richiedi_info_item_nota
{
    float:right;
    width:252px;    
}

.richiedi_info_item
{
    margin-top:15px;   
    width:400px; 
}

.richiedi_info_item label
{
    float:left;
    height:16px;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

and (on every browser expect IE7) the text `Message` and the link `Click` is aligned on the same line. Seems that span (with the red `*`) create a new line.

Why? And how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the floats (left and right) and set the div to `display:inline`, like this:

```
.richiedi_info_item_nota
{
    display:inline;
    width:252px;    
}

.richiedi_info_item label
{
    height:16px;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

---

IE7 Does not handle floats very well, especially with inline elements (`span` and `label`) so I added another div around both of the items and floated it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="richiedi_info_item">
    <div id="floating">
        <label>Message</label>
        <span style="color:Red;">&nbsp;*</span> 
    </div>

   <div class="richiedi_info_item_nota">     
       <a id="notaInfo" href="javascript:void(0);">Click</a>            
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.richiedi_info_item_nota
{
    width:21px;
    clear:both;
    float:right;
}

.richiedi_info_item
{
    margin-top:15px;   
    width:400px; 
}

.richiedi_info_item label
{
   height:16px;
    line-height:20px;
}

#floating {
    float:left;
}
```

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BBH5T/5/)

Comment: Uhm... for what I do know, a inline elements can't take a width parameter :O

Comment: Well, they can, it just won't do anything.

Comment: Open this link on whatever browser, and you will see what's my target :)

Comment: hahaha, I didn't know you were the OP (embarrassing), I have edited the answer, it appears like it worked

Comment: Oops, I'm on a role, I updated it with the wrong code, should be working now.